Why is the kernel responsible for accessing hardware, when we have device drivers?
The kernel is the most important part of the operating system, that I know. But, one of it's responsibilities is accessing hardware (write to disk, use mouse etc).
I also know that we need drivers to obtain unified access to different hardware (different brands of keyboards etc).
But - as long as we have a driver for X, it means we are able to use it as is. And if we are able to use it as is - Why can't we just use the drivers directly? Why do we need the kernel in the middle? What advantage does it creates?
I have tried asking some machine learning models for answers, and I have searched the internet for answers.
Online I have only found answers for questions about "why do we need drivers if we have kernel", and the models answers were not clear. They have claimed that the kernel is needed for security purposes (drivers could just try and settle this stuff by themselves / reach the kernel for help), and they claimed that the kernel is needed for parallel access (still - in my opinion and for my understanding, drivers could handle such thing by themselves.)

"Why can't we just use the drivers directly?" - What do you mean by direct usage of drivers? A driver code is located in the priviledged level, and application code operates in non-privileged level. So you need at least a system call, but system calls are maintained by the kernel code.

Device drivers operate at a very low level. The kernel implements higher-level abstractions.
For instance the driver for a disk implements reading and writing sectors. The kernel layers filesystems, access control, buffering, etc. on top of this.
The device driver for a NIC mostly just sends and receives data frames. The kernel implements networking layers like TCP and IP.
In addition, it's generally necessary to mediate access to devices. If a device should only be accessed by one process at a time, this is implemented by the kernel, not the driver.
